# Error running Sitecore Docker SimpleSample Project. Unable to find path $env:SITEPATH

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run this simple sitecore docker demo project
https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-demo/tree/develop/sitecore/9.0.1%20rev.%20171219%20XM1/VS2017/SimpleSample

However I keep getting this error:

> 1>Step 9/13 : RUN Rename-Item -Path **$env:SITEPATH** -NewName
>   $env:DEFAULTWEBSITENAME;     New-Item -Path $env:SITEPATH -ItemType
>   Directory | Out-Null; 1> ---> Running in 8b683e2bef08
>   **1>[91mRename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null**.

I can't find $env:SITEPATH being set in solution. Feels like Im missing some step here but can't figure out.

Looks like this issue has been raised but never answered:
https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-demo/issues/12

Comment: I get the same error using 9.0.180604, I am trying to setup a visual studio project with the standalone image. I get the same error with xm1.cm Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I was using wrong sitecore version image.

$env:SITEPATH is defined in the base image.

All variables defined in a base image are available to the images (containers) that are on base image.